PyTorch scatter max for sparse tensors?
I have the following PyTorch code
value_tensor = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(indices=query_indices.t(), values=values, size=(num_lines, img_size, img_size)).to(device=device)
value_tensor = value_tensor.to_dense()
indices = torch.arange(0, img_size * img_size).repeat(len(lines)).to(device=device)
line_tensor_flat = value_tensor.flatten()
img, _ = scatter_max(line_tensor_flat, indices, dim=0)
img = torch.reshape(img, (img_size, img_size))

Note the line: value_tensor = value_tensor.to_dense(), this is unsurprisingly slow.
However, I cannot figure out how to obtain the same results with a sparse tensor. The function in question calls reshape which is not available on sparse tensors. I'm using Scatter Max but opened to using anything that works.

You should be able to directly use scatter_max on the sparse tensor if you keep the indices that you pass to scatter_max also sparse (i.e, only the non-zero ones).
Consider this example
query_indices = torch.tensor([
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])

values = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
num_lines = 2
img_size = 3

value_tensor = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(
    indices=query_indices,
    values=values,
    size=(num_lines, img_size, img_size)
)

# need to coalesce because for some reason sparse_coo_tensor doesn't guarantee uniqueness of indices
value_tensor = value_tensor.coalesce()


Then, compute flat_indices as a sparse tensor containing just the non-zero 1-d indices (2-d indices are converted to 1-d indices similar to your arange)
indices = value_tensor.indices()
values = value_tensor.values()

batch_indices = indices[0]        # "line" (in your terminology) indices
row_indices = indices[1]
col_indices = indices[2]
flat_indices = row_indices * img_size + col_indices



You can use flat_indices to scatter_max
flattened_result, _ = scatter_max(
    values, flat_indices, dim=0, dim_size=img_size * img_size
)

per_line_max = flattened_result.reshape(img_size, img_size)


indices

tensor([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])


values

tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])


flat_indices

tensor([0, 4, 6, 0, 4, 6])

per_line_max

tensor([[4, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0],
        [6, 0, 0]])


The output I get is the same as what I get from your code.
